# Extracting only the first occurance between square brackets in a line

Tags: regex, ruby

I want extract the only the value between square brackets in a given line.
From the text

```
TID: [-1] [] [2019-07-29 10:18:41,876]  INFO
```

I want to extract the first occurrence between square brackets which is **-1**.
I tried using

```
(?<Ten ID>((^(?!(TID: )))*((?<=\[).*?(?=\]))))
```

but it gives

```
-1, ,2019-07-29 10:18:41,876
```

as resultant matches.

How to capture only the first occurrence?

You can access the regex editor [here](https://rubular.com/r/qnpsPUgCWoVMTj).

Comment: Must the string begin with `”TID: “` and/or end with that shown, or do you just want what is between the first pair of brackets regardless of what comes before and after? In other words, what must be matched as opposed to what must be extracted?

Comment: @Cary I need to extract  what is between the first pair of brackets. Is there a solution without group capturing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding

> Is there a solution without group capturing?

You may use

```
/\bTID:\s*\[\K[^\]]+(?=\])/
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/IiYX2PkHpdixub)

**Details**

- `\bTID:`  - whole word `TID` followed with a colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `[^\]]+`  - one or more chars other than `]`
- `(?=\])` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is a `]` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Is there a alternative to group capturing? Even though this is correct, my program(Fluentd) looks only for Match result section.

Comment: @Charith_32 If you need the named group, use `\bTID:\s*\[(?<Grp1>[^\]]+)\]`. If you need to only grab the full match, use `\K` and a lookahead: `\bTID:\s*\[\K[^\]]+(?=\])`, see [this Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/IiYX2PkHpdixub).

Answer (score 0):

You might capture the first occurrence in the named capturing group using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
\ATID: \[(?<Ten ID>[^\[\]]+)\]
```

- `\A` Start of string
- `TID:`  Match literally
- `\[` Match `[`
- `(?<Ten ID>` Named capturing group Ten ID

  - `[^\[\]]+` Match not `[` or `]` using a negated character class
- `)` Close group
- `\]` Match `]`

See  https://rubular.com/r/4Hc80yrDxGVgvi

Answer (score 0):

```
str = “TID:] [-1] [] [2019-07-29 10:18:41,876]  INFO”

i1 = str.index(‘[‘)
  #=> 6
i2 = str.index(‘]’, i1+1)
  #=> 9
i1.nil? || i2.nil? ? nil : str[i1+1..i2-1]
  #=> “-1”
```